# Как скомпилировать C в FASM?

Tags: c, ассемблер, fasm

У меня есть код на `C`, мне надо его скомпилировать в `FASM`. Как это сделать?
*gcc -S не подходит, он просто в asm компилирует, а нужно в FASM

Comment: Никак, это не возможно без значительного изменения ассемблерного кода, сгенерированного gcc.

Answer (score -1):

Для этого вы можете использовать, например, MinGW или любой другой компилятор. Затем вам нужно будет открыть консоль и ввести команду для компиляции из C в FASM:

```
gcc -S filename.c -o filename.asm
```

Comment: не подходит. Он компилирует в просто asm, а не в fasm

Comment: Вы можете скомпилировать код на C в FASM, используя другой компилятор, например, gcc или clang. Вам нужно будет предоставить им флаги, чтобы они могли преобразовать исходный код в FASM. Например, для gcc это будет выглядеть так:

gcc -S -masm=fasm my_file.c

Comment: Он мне пишет: gcc.exe: error: unrecognized argument in option '-masm=fasm'
gcc.exe: note: valid arguments to '-masm=' are: att intel
PS C:\Users\GANSOR\source\Systems\FASM

Comment: Это означает, что Ваша система не поддерживает флаг -masm=fasm. Вы можете использовать другой компилятор, например, Clang, который поддерживает этот флаг. Вы можете преобразовать код в FASM, используя команду clang -S -masm=fasm my_file.c.